# Pourquoi le rebattu et lancinant " ... et autres ... " ?

Tags: usage, expressions-idiomatiques, origine-ou-raison

Je lis par exemple  " ... l’âge des Vikings et ses raids soudains et meurtriers perpétue la frayeur qu’inspirèrent auparavant les Huns, les Goths *et autres* Vandales ...".

*(Calomnie d'ailleurs, ils avaient tous des civilisations très raffinées, mais, comme ils itinéraient, ils n'ont pas laissé de Parthénon - pour ce qui a survécu, comme l'orfèvrerie, l'archéologie actuelle découvre d'extraordinaires techniques, à la limite de ce que l'on pourrait faire actuellement - outre leur sens esthétique).*

Mais les Huns et les Goths n'ont rien de commun avec les Vandales, sauf qu'ils venaient de l'est.

Je pourrais dire : "dans une ferme, on élève des poules, des oies, et autres volailles (en pensant aux canards et pintades)", mais pas : "dans une ferme on élève des vaches, des poules, et autres moutons".

Pourquoi ce tic paresseux à la mode ?

---

Notons que ce serait correct si l'on disait "et autres analogues, comme les ..."

Comment: Ce serait pas mal si ceux qui font des moinssages donnaient un minimum d'explications.

Comment: @Istao Bien d'accord ! Qu'est-ce qui ne leur a pas plu ? Ils seraient plus sages de faire moins de "moinssages" sans explication ; au moins j'en aurais tiré profit.

Comment: @Istao Je soupçonne que c'est parce que Mark affirme de façon très péremptoire que « et autres » est « rebattu », « lancinant », un « tic paresseux ». Pour quelqu'un qui utilise cette tournure, c'est insultant. Je pense que la question serait mieux passée si elle demandait simplement quelle est l'origine de cette tournure qui paraît illogique.

Comment: plus-soyons (être positif, quelle gageure !) pour l'esprit de la question, et pour donner une lecture différente de 'et autres'.

Comment: @Gilles Oui, ma nature est d'être non insultant (je n'ai jamais insulté personne de ma vie, et toujours répondu ironiquement quand je l'ai été), mais certes caustique et provocateur. Nota : l'excellente dernière ligne est de Evpok

Comment: Ça reste un jugement de valeur que vous présentez comme une vérité absolue. Personnellement, je ne trouve pas votre ton insultant, je le trouve arrogant voire méprisant. Ce n’est guère mieux.

Answer (score 3):

Ce n'est pas un "tic paresseux" mais un effet de style ironique et plaisant.

> On évitera d’employer en finale un terme se rapportant mal à ce qui vient
>   d’être détaillé, sauf si l’ on recherche un effet de style particulier
>   (ironie)

J.-P. Colin (Le Robert des difficultés du Français)

> Le dernier terme de l'énumération représente normalement une classe qui
>   englobe tout ce qui a été précédemment cité. On peut cependant employer
>   cette construction de façon plaisante, le dernier terme désignant une
>   catégorie de même niveau.

Le Grand Robert

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas de connotation dans *et autres*

> - (Dans une énumération) Tomates, carottes, artichauts et autres légumes (Le petit Robert)
> - Il fut porté par terre, et autres sept ou huict avecques luy. *M. DU BELLAY*, 156  (Le Littré).

La lecture « naturelle » se contente d'ajouter : *et autres* (semblables à ceux précités) ; ce qui a bien été relevé dans la question : on ne mélange pas volatiles et mammifères.

Pourtant je me suis laissé un instant embarquer par la lecture « critique » de Mark, car les humoristes pratiquant le dénigrement systématique *et autres* beaux parleurs autour des machines à café n'emploient cette expression que dans ce contexte.

Si l'emploi calomnieux est d'intention ou d'usage courant ou se pratique dans des textes historiques niant les valeurs culturelles des autres civilisations, il est nécessaire de lire *et autres* comme ce qui vient à la suite d'une énumération (et qui appartient à la suite de ce qui vient d'être dit), et de renvoyer les intentions au contexte.

*Complément*

La façon d'extraire et de nommer un seul parmi le groupe des *autres possibles* 
comme dans  « tomates, carottes et autres navets » est sciemment biseauté, car navets à un consonance péjorative lorsque l'on parle de film.

« Tomates, carottes et autres courgettes » est tout à fait audible pour une recette de cuisine qui ne dirait rien de la qualité des tomates (cerise, cœur de bœuf, de Marmande, …) ou des courgettes qui peuvent être grosses, longues, rondes… Cela revient à dire « quels que soient le nom et la forme des tomates et des courgettes, la recette sera valable ».

Comment: Je pense que tu n'as pas compris la question : elle ne porte pas sur « tomates, carottes et autres légumes » mais sur « tomates, carottes et autres navets ». Ce qui se dit effectivement, même si ça a l'air illogique.

Comment: @Gilles ... *et autres Vandales* sonne comme *et autres légumes*, car *vandale* est devenu un nom commun, c'est pourquoi je n'ai pas 'trébuché' sur ce mot.